# Saving malayalam text to laravel database

Tags: laravel-5.3

I want to save the malayalam text I have entered into a textarea to mysql. But when I try to accept the malayalam content on form submission it is returning like `à´¾àµ€àµ‚à´¬à´—à´—à´œà´œ` characters. However I have used utf-8 encoding. Can anyone help me? The code I have done is as follows:

```
public function import(Request $request) {

if ($request->hasFile('import_file')) {
    $path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();
    $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {

            })->get();
    $randomNum = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz"), 0, 11);
    $role_id = session('role_id');
    if (!empty($data) && $data->count()) {
        foreach ($data->toArray() as $key => $v) {

            $insert[] = ['subid' => $v['subid'], 'totalanswers' => $v['totalanswers'],
                'answer1' => $v['answer1'], 'answer2' => $v['answer2'], 'answer3' => $v['answer3'],
                'answer4' => $v['answer4'], 'answer5' => $v['answer5'], 'question' => utf8_encode($v['question']), 'hint' => $v['hint'],
                'questiontype' => $v['questiontype'], 'status' => $v['status'], 'questioncategory' => $v['questioncategory'],
                'created_at' => $v['created_at'], 'updated_at' => $v['updated_at'], 'correctanswer' => $v['correctanswer'],
                'role_id' => $role_id, 'tempid' => $randomNum
            ];


        }
    }

    if (!empty($insert)) {

        DB::table('questions_malayalam')->insert($insert);
        session(array('randomid' => $randomNum));
        return redirect(route('testquestion.order'));
    }
}

Session::flash('message', "Please Check your file, Something is wrong there.");
return Redirect::back();
```

}

i needed english to other languages

Comment: I think you forgot to provide the code.

Comment: plz help..where to change

Comment: The author has technical problems. Let him correct them.

Comment: Below the question there are reference commands to *share*, *edit*, .... Use edit, of course. Add the code.